# How to remove Cache-Control and modify Cache-Control in CodeIgniter 4?

Tags: browser-cache, cache-control, codeigniter-4

Getting set header cache issue

I want to modify code. how to remove Cache-Control: and modify
Cache-Control:?

https://prnt.sc/1qbk7h6

I have set code but this code is append.

```
$response = service('response');

$options = [    'max-age'  => 60, ];

$response->setCache($options);

$response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public');
```

Comment: You can try removing the header first with `removeHeader()`; my assumption is that because `Cache-Control` can take a comma-separated string of multiple options, `setHeader` is handling that header as an Array and adding `public` to the list rather than overwriting it outright.

Comment: removeHeader() not working 
code:
$response->removeHeader("Cache-Control");